# UITextView is not editable on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

This may be stupid question,
I searched for this lot and found multiple answers. but didn't helped me lot

I am adding `UItextView` on my `UITableViewCell`. (not custom cell)

Here is my code

```
UITextView *ansTextV = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
ansTextV.editable = YES;
ansTextV.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[ansTextV setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:25]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:ansTextV];
[ansTextV release];
```

The `UITextView` is not editable.
but same time when I add this textview on `self.view` it is editable.
But not on `UITableView`.

I checked for `UITableview` interaction and `UITableViewCell` editable.
But didn't work.

What I am doing wrong.
Thanks for help

Comment: show your code for cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @Dheeraj above is the code
just returning cell at the end

Comment: same code is working at my end.

Comment: I solved it by giving height for it in heightforRow thanks to all sorry for trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    UITextView *ansTextV = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
    ansTextV.editable = YES;
    ansTextV.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [ansTextV setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:25]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:ansTextV];
    ansTextV=nil;

    return cell;
}
```

I had made sample code for It is working at my end.
I had use storyboard and added tableview on viewcontroller 
plz check screen shot[image]

Comment: also i have added textview programatically.

Comment: I solved it
by giving height for it in heightforRow
thanks to all
sorry for trouble

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[ansTextV setEditable:YES];
[ansTextV setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

And btw I think there might be another problem.

```
UITextView *ansTextV = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
```

Check what is the size of `cell.frame.size.width` & `cell.frame.size.height`.

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: @Rashid, cell.frame.size.width = 320 and cell.frame.size.height = 85, this is what I get When I NSlog the frames of cell.

Answer (score 0):

If It is working when added on UIView then your delegate are set properly so now try :

```
cell.userinteractionenabled=YES;
yourTableView.userenterationEnabled=YES;
```

May be It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `adding` following line before you `return Cell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath Method`.

```
[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:ansTextV];
```

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad() method, try this code :

```
[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Also in your cellForRowAtIndexPath() method, try this code :

```
[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell.contentView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell.contentView addSubview:ansTextV];
[cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:ansTextV];
[ansTextV setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[ansTextV setEditable:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you must be adding at backside of something, means to make it usable, you have to bring it to front try this :

```
[yourTableViewName bringSubviewToFront:yourTextView];
```

this will bring your backView to front and it will be intractionable.

Answer (score 0):

A known issue is when the cell's `contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled` is set to `true` by default, you will have to set it to false in `cellForRow` so the responder chain will reach your `UITextField`:

```
cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```